# Replace value in a column and row with a given row index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of urls and verified urls and add a column with the levenstein ratio, which compares the two types of urls for each row.

Here is an example of my pandas dataframe:

```
                       url                  url_ok2
13          10hanover.org/                      NaN
15  111140.cevadosite.com/      aerorealestate.net/
42         18brownlow.com/      18brownlow.com:443/
57           1granary.com/    1granary.com/journal/
61             1rs.org.uk/                  1rs.io/
79   2020visionnetwork.eu/  network.crowdhelix.com/
```

Here is my script:

```
import Levenshtein as lev

to_test['lev_ratio'] = None
for i in range(to_test.shape[0]):
    to_test.iloc[i]['lev_ratio'] =  lev.ratio(str(to_test.iloc[i].url),str(to_test.iloc[i].url_ok2))
```

But the values are not replaced, see dataframe after running script:
                           url                  url_ok2 lev_ratio
    13          10hanover.org/                      NaN      None
    15  111140.cevadosite.com/      aerorealestate.net/      None
    42         18brownlow.com/      18brownlow.com:443/      None
    57           1granary.com/    1granary.com/journal/      None
    61             1rs.org.uk/                  1rs.io/      None
    79   2020visionnetwork.eu/  network.crowdhelix.com/      None

But when I check lev.ratio(str(to_test.iloc[i].url),str(to_test.iloc[i].url_ok2)), it gives me the corresponding value, i.e. `lev.ratio(str(to_test.iloc[0].url),str(to_test.iloc[0].url_ok2))` returns

```
0.45454545454545453
```

How can I replace the values in lev_ratio column for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.apply` to the dataFrame:

```
df['lev_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: lev.ratio(str(x.url),str(x.url_ok2)), axis=1)
```